# difference in merge behavior in github

Tags: git, github

I have a PR in github where in the UI, it shows that it can be merged without conflicts:

[image]

But when I attempt to merge master into the PR from the command line locally, git reports merge conflicts:

```
Olivers-MacBook-Pro:incrementum oliverpike$ git merge master
Auto-merging src/components/StudyPanel/index.js
Auto-merging src/components/StudyPanel/StudyPanel.less
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/components/StudyPanel/StudyPanel.less
Removing spec/indexSpec.js
Auto-merging server/routes/response.js
Auto-merging server/routes/index.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in server/routes/index.js
Auto-merging server/routes/dispute/validator.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in server/routes/dispute/validator.js
Auto-merging package.json
Auto-merging npm-shrinkwrap.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in npm-shrinkwrap.json
Auto-merging migrations/20170909131130-responses.js
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in migrations/20170909131130-responses.js
Recorded preimage for 'migrations/20170909131130-responses.js'
Recorded preimage for 'npm-shrinkwrap.json'
Recorded preimage for 'server/routes/dispute/validator.js'
Recorded preimage for 'server/routes/index.js'
Recorded preimage for 'src/components/StudyPanel/StudyPanel.less'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

If someone can explain this difference in behavior, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Github is showing you what happens if you try to merge your PR into master. Whereas you are trying to `merge master into the PR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and merge the PR branch locally to see what those conflicts are:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b  pull/ID/head BRANCHNAME
git checkout master
git merge BRANCHNAME
```

(instead of merging master)

You should get conflicts for you to resolve (or to mention to the author of that PR, for him/her to resolve and update his/her PR)

Comment: The issue was that I was merging master into the PR branch rather than vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say anything definite from the information in the question, but I can say what could help you to investigate it. There is a `merge` reference for a PR which you can fetch:

```
git fetch https://github.com/your/repo refs/pull/12345/merge:refs/remotes/origil-pr/12345-merge
```

(substitute relevant details of your repository and PR)

Then you could verify that merge parents are same as you think, and see what is the resolution f there were any conflicts.